# Is it okay to install `npm` as a dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, asyncapi

We want to use [AsyncAPI](https://asyncapi.io/) to document our RabbitMQ messaging. Therefore, we installed [asyncapi/generator](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator) as a npm dependency.

If you have a look at the `package.json` you can see that it references [npmi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmi) as a dependency which in turn is referencing to [global-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-npm). If we want to run it, a globally installed node and npm is necessary.

Now if we run the generator (`$ ag ./docs/asyncapi.yaml @asyncapi/html-template --output ./docs/asyncapi/ --force-write`) on a machine which has no globally installed npm following error message appears:

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/global-npm/index.js:13
  throw err
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npm'
    at throwNotFoundError (/path/to/project/node_modules/global-npm/index.js:11:13)
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/global-npm/index.js:39:5
...
```

As a workaround we declared npm itself as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@asyncapi/generator": "^1.1.4",
    "@asyncapi/html-template": "^0.15.4",
    "@asyncapi/markdown-template": "^0.11.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.9",
    ...
```

I've never seen such a thing. Is this acceptable or do we need to install our npm on our machines separatly?

Comment: You need to install npm on your machines rather than having it as a dependancy. How would you run `npm install` on the machine if it's not there ?

Comment: Okay you're right. Generally speaking, do I even need to install npm separatly? In which case?

Comment: Probably if you would use other package manager on the machine and inside the project npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only had this issue in our CI/CD pipeline working with maven-frontend-plugin which is installing node/npm.  npm is located in `node/node_modules`. This is no location where AsyncAPI looks for npm. In order to fix this issue we link the npm-cli.js (which is npm) from
the maven-frontend-plugin to a well known place where AsyncApi looks up for npm `node_modules/.bin`.

`- ln -sf "$(pwd)/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin/npm"`

Answer (score 1):

if you run `ag` you must have installed it with npm initially right? so npm is most probably on this machine already.

The error you have, I saw it on windows only, when you have the generator as dependency, and most likely you use nvm.

Solution was [this](https://github.com/asyncapi/ts-nats-template/blob/master/package.json#L34), so manual bump of `global-npm` to have [this](https://github.com/dracupid/global-npm/issues/5) fixed in `npmi`. This is a workaround,long term I think we need to get rid of `npmi` dependency from the generator I think

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation. I'm creating a answer for our case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060037/4065938